# Characters in filesystem replaced by Unicode boxes after upgrading to 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, fonts, 20.04, unicode

After upgrading to 20.04 LTS, the characters in the terminal, Nautilus, and Settings menu are all being displayed as boxes, as shown in the screenshot. There is no issue with the browser, or the Activities or Applications menu, but any text inside an application, say, Calculator has the text replaced by the characters.
I have tried

```bsh
find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
find ~/.fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
fc-cache -fr
```

as well as

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

but these haven't worked.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No, I had tried the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for the Calculator app, but I found that for my terminal I simply had to go to Preferences and choose a new font. As soon as I selected a new font all the rest of them showed up correctly. This after trying all kinds of updates to font families, replacing the .bashrc file, changing font file permissions, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but it didn't work.
I am doing a fresh install to resolve this for now, however, I'm curious as to why this problem occurred.